# Finding the path from the root node to a specified node in a tree using recursion

Tags: java, tree, concatenation

**Background:**
This is my first time using a tree, I was tasked to create a tree using the royal family using file data.txt

*data.txt:*

```
King George VI
King George VI > Princess Margaret
Princess Margaret > David, Viscount Linley
Princess Margaret > Lady Sarah
Lady Sarah > Samuel Chatto
Lady Sarah > Arthur Chatto
David, Viscount Linley > Charles Armstrong-Jones
David, Viscount Linley > Margarita Armstrong-Jones
King George VI > Queen Elizabeth II
Queen Elizabeth II > Charles, Prince of Wales
Charles, Prince of Wales > Prince William of Wales
Prince William of Wales > Prince George of Cambridge
Charles, Prince of Wales > Prince Harry of Wales
Queen Elizabeth II > Anne, Princess Royal
Anne, Princess Royal > Peter Phillips
Peter Phillips > Savannah Phillips
Peter Phillips > Isla Phillips
Anne, Princess Royal > Zara Tindall
Queen Elizabeth II > Andrew, Duke of York
Andrew, Duke of York > Princess Beatrice of York
Andrew, Duke of York > Princess Eugenie of York
Queen Elizabeth II > Edward, Earl of Wessex
Edward, Earl of Wessex > Lady Louise Windsor
Edward, Earl of Wessex > James, Viscount Severn
```

**Background**(Cotd.)**:** I then search for the Princess Beatrice of York, and find her respective node.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Define a variable to store the root node
        TNode<String> root = null;

        //TODO: SETUP TREE DATA
        //1. Use Scanner to read the data.txt file
        //2. The first line in data.txt is the root node
        //3. For each line in data.txt in the format A > B
        //      - *find* the A node
        //      - add B as a child of A
        try
        {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
            while(s.hasNextLine())
            {
                String[] split = null;
                if(!s.nextLine().contains(">"))
                {
                    root = new TNode<String>(s.nextLine());
                }else{
                     split = s.nextLine().split(" > ");
                }
                find(root,split[0]).setParent(new TNode(split[3]));
            }
            s.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //TODO: test printPath method
        TNode<String> child = find(root, "Princess Beatrice of York");
        String path = getPath( child );
        System.out.println(path);

    }
```

*find method:*

```
    /**
     *  @return node if its data matches name, or return a child node with data that matches name
     */
    public static TNode<String> find(TNode<String> node, String name)
    {
        //use recursion to check this node and all of its children to see if their data matches the specified name
        if(node.getData().equals(name))
        {
            return node;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < node.getChildren().size(); i++)
        {
            return find(node.getChildren().get(i),name);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Goal:** return a String containing the path from the root node to the specified node separated by ' -> ' starting from the child node

*My attempt:*

```
    public static String getPath(TNode<String> node)
    {
        //use recursion to concatenate the getPath of this node's parent with this node's data
        if(!node.getParent().equals(null))
            return getPath(node.getParent()) + " -> " + node.getData(); 
        return getPath(node.getParent());
    }
```

**Questions:**

1.

> is this even possible in the first place

2.

> how can I concatenate a string if there i no string that I can concatenate.

3.

> What are some ways that can help me figure out the logic to recursive problems

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find path to node in Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232858/find-path-to-node-in-tree)

Comment: Please restrict yourself to asking only one question per question, and make sure the code you post is the minimum necessary to illustrate your problem or support your question.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi, If I read it correctly, i believe it doesn't. That post is from the root. I am trying to get the path starting from the child node to the root.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely possible. Just by looking at it, you can trace back from `Princess Beatrice of York` to `King George VI`.

To create the family line string (assuming that's what you want) you can store each person in a `TNode` and concatenate the names with a `>` between them, starting at the root.

As far as learning to think about recursive algorithms, start with something simpler like a string's length or computing the factorial of a number.