# How to get the path to a node in n-ary tree?

Tags: tree, lisp

I'm working in gnu lisp and want to get the path to a certain node.
I've managed to solve the problem for a binary tree but can't find the correct recursive rule if the tree is n-ary. The tree is represented (root (subtree1) (subtree2) ...).
So, how the get the path to a node in n-ary tree using GNU Lisp?

Code for binary:

```
;checks if element e is in l
(defun partof(l e)
    (cond
        ((null l) nil)
        ((equal l e) T)
        ((atom l) nil)
        (T (find T (mapcar (lambda (l) (partof l e)) l)))))

;get the path   
(defun path(l e)
    (cond
        ((null l) nil)
        ((equal (car l) e) (list (car l))) ;if the element is the root of subtree return it
        ((partof (cadr l) e) (cons (car l) (path (cadr l) e))) ;if it is in the first subtree, get the root and check in first subtree until you get to it
        ((partof (caddr l) e) (cons (car l) (path(caddr l) e))) ; get the root and parse the second subtree
        (T nil))) ;here i can't find the rule to check in the rest of the subtrees
```

I also interested in a totally new way, not just completing this one.
A n-ary tree is like this: (root (subtree1) (subtree2) (subtree3) ...), For example (A (B (C) (D)) (E (F) (G)) (H (I) (J))) is a complete tree.

```
                   A
               /   |   \
              B    E    H
             /\    /\   /\
            C D   F G  I J
```

Comment: "The tree is represented (root (subtree1) (subtree2) ...).  Can you clarify about the structure of the tree?  And what are you trying to return as a path?

Comment: I put an example of tree in question. The path from root to node(all the node which are passed to get to the requsted node). Path to D: A, B, D.

Comment: You also may be interested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355969/how-to-get-the-path-from-root-to-a-given-node-on-a-binary-tree).

Comment: @Mark, the post is for BINARY tree. I wrote the solution for that, i'm interested in n-ary tree. Thanks.

Comment: @CristiDeac Stack Overflow is a site for professional and enthusiast programmers.  Most professional and enthusiast programmers would be *appreciative* of references for solutions to *similar* problems, because professional and enthusiast programmers are willing to consider solutions to similar situations how they can be modified for new situations.  Mark didn't claim that that post would solve your problem, just that it's similar and might be useful or interesting.  Stack Overflow isn't a code factory;  demanding code that solves some specific problem isn't the best way to get helpful results

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i agree with you and i'm very thankful to Mark for giving me the solution. I don't understand why do you think that i didn't appreciated Mark by answering at his post. I did it in order to comunicate and express my needs, to have a good communication. I've also readed and analysed that article and thought that it is better to let Mark know that i still didn't find my solution. I don't think that is very enthusiastic nor professional to critize ( offend) people for a comment which is mented to provide a good communication. Thanks for your advice, i'll consider it for next posts.

Comment: @CristiDeac I may have misread the intent of your previous comment.  Tone does not always come across well in text, and the comment (as I read it) appeared some what irritated.  Writing "BINARY" in all capitals gave the impression of (and I'm exaggerating), "the post is for BINARY trees. [Didn't you read the question?  I'm not looking for BINARY trees, but N-ARY trees.]"  Writing "thanks" with a period afterward can also come across as [angry](http://www.newrepublic.com/article/115726/period-our-simplest-punctuation-mark-has-become-sign-anger).  Your comment makes it sound like you didn't

Comment: intend any of that tone, so please accept my apologies for misreading the intent of your comment.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i'm glad that we made it clear now. no need to apologize. I'll try to be more explicit next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Path from root to node (recursive approach)

```
(defun find-path (tree node &optional path)
  (if (eq (car tree) node)
      (reverse (cons node path))
      (reduce (lambda (p x)
                (or p (find-path x
                                 node
                                 (cons (car tree) path))))
              (cdr tree)
              :initial-value nil)))
```

Works on GNU CLISP 2.49:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *tree* '(a (b (c) (d)) (e (f) (g)) (h (i) (j))))
*TREE*
CL-USER> (find-path *tree* 'd)
(A B D)
```

### Path from one arbitrary node to another

OP didn't say what kind of path he/she wants to get: from root to node, or between two arbitrary nodes. So this function solves more general task of finding path between two arbitrary nodes of a tree.

```
(defun find-path* (tree x y)
  (labels ((till-d (a b i)
             (if (and (eq (car a) (car b))
                      a
                      b)
                 (till-d (cdr a) (cdr b) (1+ i))
                 i)))
    (let* ((x-path (find-path tree x))
           (y-path (find-path tree y))
           (pos (till-d x-path y-path 0)))
      (append (reverse (nthcdr (1- pos) x-path))
              (nthcdr pos y-path)))))
```

Works like this:

```
CL-USER> (find-path* *tree* 'd 'c)
(D B C)
CL-USER> (find-path* *tree* 'd 'g)
(D B A E G)
CL-USER> (find-path* *tree* 'b 'h)
(B A H)
CL-USER> (find-path* *tree* 'd 'd)
(D)
```

Now a number of tasks also can be solved quite easily (distance between nodes, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Remembering what I learned about recipes and "trusting the recursion", I can offer the following:

```
CL-USER> (defun path (tree elt)
           (labels ((find-path (tree elt path)
                      (cond ((null tree) nil)
                            ((equal (car tree) elt) (cons elt path))
                            (t (some #'(lambda (sub)
                                         (find-path sub elt (cons (car tree) path)))
                                     (cdr tree))))))
             (reverse (find-path tree elt '()))))
STYLE-WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::PATH in DEFUN(A (B (C) (D)) (E (F) (G)) (H (I) (J)))
PATH
CL-USER> (path '(A (B (C) (D)) (E (F) (G)) (H (I) (J))) 'D)
(A B D)
```

Note that I've been using SBCL here, but it should at least give you an idea...

Answer (score -2):

## This is no way different than finding the path of a node of binary tree. .there is solution for binary tree I am posting.. you can just implement the same for N way tree.

/ / instead of calling the recursive function for left and right child , you have to write a loop to call for the all the child and you will get it.

package binary_tree_path;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/*
 * You are given a binary tree ( root Node) .. and a key is given which may / or may not be in the tree.
You have to find the full path from the root to the Node.

Example

```
                A
           /           \
       B                C
         \               /
          D           E
        /    \           \
      K      L        M
    /
Z
```

you have given node Z ( or the key for the Node ) and given Node A( root)
So your output should be

A  B D K Z

if M is given the output should be 
A C E M

*/

public class main_class {
    public static void main(String args[] ) {

```
    //first create tree
    Node rootNode = new Node ('A' , new Node('B',null,
                                             new Node('D',
                                                      new Node('K',
                                                               new Node('Z',null,
                                                               null),null),
                                                      new Node('L',null,null))),
                                    new Node('C',
                                             new Node('E',
                                                      null,
                                                      new Node('M',null,null)),null) );

    ArrayList <Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
    System.out.println(getPath(rootNode,'Z',path));
    System.out.println(path);
    path = new ArrayList<Node>();
    System.out.println(getPath(rootNode,'M',path));
    System.out.println(path);

}
static boolean getPath(Node rootNode, char key, ArrayList<Node> path ){
    //return true if the node is found
    if( rootNode==null)
        return false;
    if (rootNode.getVal()==key){
        path.add(rootNode);
        return true;
    }
    boolean left_check = getPath( rootNode.left,key,path);
    boolean right_check = getPath( rootNode.right,key,path);
    if ( left_check || right_check){
        path.add(rootNode);
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
static class Node {
    char val;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    public Node( char val, Node left, Node right){
        this.left=left;
        this.right=right;
        this.val=val;
    }
    public char getVal(){
        return val;
    }
   public String toString(){
        return " " + val + " ";
    }
}
```

}