# Is there a term for 'position of a node in a binary tree about how to traverse to it from the root'?

Tags: algorithm, tree

Is there a term for 'position of a node in a binary tree about how to traverse to it from the root'?

For example, suppose there's a binary tree like this:

```
    r
   / \
  b   c
 / \   \
d   e   a
   /
  h
```

And 'e's position is [left, right] from root 'r', or [false, true] from 'r'; 'h's position is [left, right, left] from root 'r', or [false, true, false] from 'r'

What's the most concise term and easy-to-understand term for describing this kind of information for a node in the binary tree? For example, is there a concise enough term XXXX so that 'the XXXX of node h' can express this information about node h in the tree?

Comment: *PATH* ? The *path* from the root to the node?

Comment: thanks. I didn't think of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Wikipedia site for [binary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), they mention *paths*, so it seems like a term you can use..

Also, this question uses the term as well:

[how to get the path from root to a given node on a binary tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355969/how-to-get-the-path-from-root-to-a-given-node-on-a-binary-tree)